# jquery code that searches for an item in a list

Tags: search, jquery

Looking for jquery code that searches for an item in a list, like ID or Title.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');

function init(){
 var cContext = new SP.ClientContext('siteurl');
    var oList = cContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List name');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
        '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
    cContext.load(collListItem,'Include(Id,Title)');
    cContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

        while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            var title= oListItem.get_item('Title');
        if(title == 'Your Title'){    // check for your desired title 
            // alert(title);
        }

    }
}
```